# Fetching all post parameter from a RootResource in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey

While using a Root- and SubResource in Jersey I annotated the RootResource like this to receive the form parameter param1.

```
@Path("some/path")
public SubResource doSomething(@FormParam("param1") String param1) {
...
}
```

Everything worked as I expected it to be, but, when the parameter is not given than jersey will return an internal error status code (500). In general I would say that this should be something like a bad request (400) or so.

What I then tried to do is, I added a `MultivaluedMap<String, String> form` into the parameter list (See: [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e247) Example 2.19)

```
@Path("some/path")
public SubResource doSomething(MultivaluedMap<String, String> form) {
...
}
```

In this case I should be able to handle the form parameters for myself, but `form` did not get populated. Probably because of the missing @POST annotation.

My Question: Do you know a way, besides handling a HttpServletRequest which I find frustrating, so that I get my post parameters?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are passing the form parameters to the the sub resource locator, as opposed to the sub resource itself?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question but i am not passing parameters to the sub resource locator. The code snippets represent the same method, just simply altered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish, but none of your examples seem valid to me. Since you are trying to pass processing onto a sub-resource you really should be dealing with the parameters there, instead of in the root resource. Heres an example:

```
@Path("/root/path")
public class RootResource {
    @Path("/sub/path")
    public SubResource doSomething() {
       // return an instance of your sub resource
    }
}

@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SubResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    public Collection<SomeBean> getAll() {}

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}
    public SomeBean getSingle() {}

    @POST
    @Path("/")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public SomeBean reallyDoSomething(@FormParam("param1") final String param) {
       // do ... something
    }
}
```

---

***EDIT***

If you need access to form parameters in order to initialize your sub resource then access them via the HTTP servlet request:

```
public class RootResource {
    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Path("/sub/path")
    public SubResource doSomething() {
        final Map<String, String> params = request.getParameterMap();
        // process the parameters 
        // return an instance of your sub resource
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, i've should have cleared my intentions a bit more. In my case it is all about generalization. I have a general event class with an attribute `private Date created;` and another attribute `private String eventType;` that I fill with form parameters in the RootResource. I then pass the event object over to the SubResource to handle the more specific derived event objects where other form parameters come in to play.

Comment: All i am saying is, that I don't want jersey to return a 500 status code for missing form parameters. So I want a list of form parameters in the RootResource to handle the general form data for the general event objects.

Comment: Jersey will deserialize nulls for all missing parameters. Are you handling the case that these values may be null in your program?

Comment: I set `@DefaultValue("somevalue")` and checked `param1` for `null`. It didn't even get to that point. Jersey throws an exception that looks like this: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Exception injecting parameters for sub-locator method:...

Comment: Right. Because the specification does not define behavior for injecting parameters for sub resource locators. If you really need access to some parameters in order to initialize your sub resource then you should inject them to your root resource as instance variables. See edit to my answer for an example.

Comment: That didn't work, at least not in my tests. `request.getParameterMap()` has no form parameter.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, this is because Jersey consumes the request entity. More on this: https://java.net/projects/jersey/lists/users/archive/2010-01/message/19